# Unable to access ActiveXObjects inside an HTA worker

Tags: javascript, excel, hta, activexobject

I have an IE 11 HTA that extracts data from various Excel spreadsheets which the user chooses at run time.  There are several categories of spreadsheets, and several examples of each category (daily, weekly, monthly reports, etc) so the user has to choose one spreadsheet from each category at run-time.  This is working well, but it's slower than I would like as it's using a blocking, single-threaded logic, so when the HTA is opening a spreadsheet from a particular category and extracting the data the HTA is on hold.

I've been trying to switch to a multi-threaded model using web workers to do the job of opening the spreadsheets so that the HTA is not blocked, but I've been unable to do so as the worker files seem to be unable to access ActiveXObjects.

As an example, here is a trimmed-down main file:

```
function main () {

    var output = document.getElementById ('output');
    var myWorker = new Worker ('worker.js');
    sendOut ('Calling worker.');
    myWorker.postMessage ('');

    myWorker.onmessage = function (m) {
        sendOut (m.data);
    }
}

function sendOut (m) {
    output.innerHTML += '<br /> ' + (m);
}

window.callWorker = main;
```

While the worker.js file looks like this:

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject ('Scripting.FileSystemObject')

onmessage = function (m) {
    postMessage ('Worker responding.');
}
```

If I comment out the first line of the worker.js file, the HTA runs as expected and the messages 'Calling worker.' and 'Worker responding.' appears in the 'output' element.  However, if it's left uncommented, I get the error message 'Automation server can't create object'.

From this, it looks like worker files can't access ActiveXObjects, but I cannot find anything to confirm or explain this.

I've also tried creating ActiveXObjects in the main file and passing them as arguments like this:

```
function main () {

    var fso = new ActiveXObject ('Scripting.FileSystemObject')
    var output = document.getElementById ('output');
    var myWorker = new Worker ('worker1.js');
    sendOut ('Calling worker.');
    myWorker.postMessage (fso);

    myWorker.onmessage = function (m) {
        sendOut (m.data);
    }
}

function sendOut (m) {
    output.innerHTML += '<br /> ' + (m);
}

window.callWorker = main;
```

But now I just get the error "DataCloneError".  I've not been able to find any reference materials on this, but it looks like what I'm trying to do simple isn't possible.  Is anyone able to confirm this, or do you know of a way around it?

Comment: Unfortunately web workers are not permitted to use the extended privileges htas have.

Comment: That would explain that.  Thanks!